# import issue of "serialization.json.JSON" class in actionscript:

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, intellij-idea, import, actionscript

I'm working on a project using actionscript and Flex. For some reason I have a problem importing the **com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON** class.
When I'm working only with the FlexSDK files and try to use it I'm getting
the following error:

> Error:(142, 70) [..]: Error code: 1120: Access of undefined property
>   JSON.

And of course IntelliJ marks this file and the import in red.

On the other hand when I import the **corelib.swc** that includes this file I get the following error:

> Error:[..]: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. JSON
>   (from /Volumes/backup/FlexSDK/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc(JSON,
>   Walker)) and com.adobe.serialization.json:JSON (from
>   /Volumes/backup/.../libs/corelib.swc(com.adobe.serialization.json:JSON))
>   are available.

What is going on here? How can I solve this?

Comment: What SDK version are you using? Did IntelliJ choose the airglobal.swc for you, or you manually added it? JSON is a built-in class and has been for quite awhile now. It seems like the airglobal.swc is referring to the built-in JSON class, and when you include corelib.swc it defines another JSON class.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a top level class available in all the scopes since FP11. Trying to import any class with name JSON will result in an error. If (for some reason) you really do not want to use the already available JSON class and instead import a custom one you'll have to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Intellij, the best you can do is use the JSON class from the current SDK that you have, it has the methods parse() and stringify(). those two methods do the same as the corelib methods for the json.

In case you wanted to use the com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON it will enter in conflict with the one declared in the SDK.

Hope the information is useful